# Upgrade to newer JDK (6 -> 7) causes performance degradation of GC

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot

I have a server that runs with jvm6 and the following params:

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx2g myapp.jar
```

lately our IT has upgraded the machine to JVM7, and I think we are having performance problems,

Is there a way to work with JVM6 GC algorithm and pretend we still running on JVM6??

How can I test performance?

Comment: *and I think we are having performance problems* any actual timings? what makes you think it's GC problem?

Comment: You might also want to upgrade any library that assumes JDK6 and, if you haven't done so already, migrate your code base to JDK7 as well. Migrating to a new JVM version is not always as easy as flipping a switch.

Comment: What about other changes; if you went to 64 bits, such [options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) as -`XX:+UseCompressedOops` come into play.

Comment: The default GC algorithms are the same in 6 & 7. The most likely explanantion is that it is something else. Can you post more details (exactly which versions, precise command lines used to start the process, operating system, etc)?

Comment: can you give some hints on how you came to conclusion that you're performance is degraded ? when you say performance, is it about speed or memory footprint ?